# Get all the attribute values of nodes from an XML File

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have created an xml file like below

```
<Engagements>
    <User name ="jjjj">
        <Engagement id="1111"/>
    </User>
    <User name ="kkkk">
        <Engagement id="2222"/>
    </User>
</Engagements>
```

I need to get all the id values from all of the `Engagement` nodes.

This is what I currently have:

```
public static void ParseXml(XmlDocument xmlFile) 
{
  XmlNodeList nodes = xmlFile.SelectNodes("//Engagement"); 
  foreach (XmlNode node in nodes) 
  { 
    // What goes here?
  } 
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Please post your current code and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: You have _two_ `Engagement` nodes. Which id do you want?

Comment: I want to get all the id's of the node Engagement

Comment: please see the edited comment

Comment: public static void ParseXml(XmlDocument xmlFile)
        {
            XmlNodeList nodes = xmlFile.SelectNodes("//Engagement");

            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                
            }
        }

Comment: Please edit your question to add detail to it instead of in comments. Comments are not a good place for posting code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use LINQ to XML:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var ids = doc.Descendants("Engagement").Attributes("id").Select(x => x.Value);

foreach (var id in ids)
    Console.WriteLine(id);
```

Comment: I have searched a while to solve this. But your answer is the best. Im wondering why he never accepted your answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
var xmlString = "...";  // <--- your xml here
var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(xmlString);
var xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Engagements/User");
var test = "";
if (xnList != null) 
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
    if (xn.Attributes != null)
    {
        if (xn.Attributes[0].Value == "kkkk")
        {
            if (xn.FirstChild.Attributes != null)
            {
                var xmlElement = xn.FirstChild.Attributes[0].Value;
                if (xmlElement != null)
                {
                    test = xmlElement;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
Console.WriteLine(test);
Console.Read();
```

Comment: Please, insert the text as introduction to the answer provided, not as a comment. Comment flagged.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to get all ids in a list

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(yourxmlStringInput);
var engagements = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Engagement");
var ids = (from engagement in engagements 
          select engagement.Attributes["id"].Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If those other great answers don't do it for you, maybe showing you the answer in the same context you are stuck in:

```
public static void ParseXml(XmlDocument xmlFile) 
{
  XmlNodeList nodes = xmlFile.SelectNodes("//Engagement"); 
  foreach (XmlNode node in nodes) 
  { 
    string id = node.Attributes["id"].InnerText;
    // Do whatever you need to with each ID here.
  } 
}
```

If you only want the attribute portion of the nodes that have an `id` attribute you can restrict your [XPath query](http://visualcsharptutorials.com/net-framework/using-xpath-to-select-nodes) by specifying that you require that attribute and select it like so:

`XmlNodeList nodes = xmlFile.SelectNodes("//Engagement[@id]/@id");`

Each node returned with this query will be an ID attribute node, so you can get the value in your loop using `node.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

var xmlString = "";

```
        var xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(xmlString);

        foreach (XmlNode node in xml.SelectNodes("//Engagement[@id]"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes["id"].Value);
        }
```